# Comprobar si una cadena dada, que solo contiene ()/[]/{}, tiene sus paréntesis abiertos cerrados por el mismo tipo de paréntesis, en Python

Tags: python-3.x

Espero no sonar raro aquí, básicamente, suponga que usted tiene las siguientes cadenas:

```
s1 = '{[]}'

s2 = '[(])'

s3 = '()[]{}'
```

Y usted desea escribir una función que verifique que dichas cadenas son `'valid'` sí:

> **Sus paréntesis que abren son cerrados por el mismo tipo de paréntesis**

Así que, la salida de dicha función para las cadenas de arriba sería la siguiente:

```
theFunction(s1)
```

> **valid**

```
theFunction(s2)
```

> **NOT valid**

```
theFunction(s3)
```

> **valid**

Yo pensé en diseñar la función así:

```
def theFunction(s):
   the_dic = {'(':')',
              '[':']',
              '{':'}',
              }

   if any(s.startswith(ch) for ch in the_dic.keys()):
      for char in s:
         #...?
         result = 'valid'
   else: 
      result = 'NOT valid'

   return result
```

Pero, me quedo corto en los conocimientos de avanzados de ciclos anidados, ¿puedo tener algo de ayuda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución simple:

```
pairs = ['()', '[]', '{}']

def validar(cadena):
    while cadena:
        largo_inicial = len(cadena)
        for pair in pairs:
            cadena = cadena.replace(pair, '')
        largo_final = len(cadena)
        if largo_inicial == largo_final:
            return False
    return True
```

La idea es ir eliminado cada par `[]`, `{}`, `()` de la cadena hasta llegar a una cadena vacía (cadena válida) o detectar que no fue posible realizar ningún reemplazo (cadena no válida).

#### Demo

```
pairs = ['()', '[]', '{}']

def validar(cadena):
    while cadena:
        largo_inicial = len(cadena)
        for pair in pairs:
            cadena = cadena.replace(pair, '')
        largo_final = len(cadena)
        if largo_inicial == largo_final:
            return False
    return True


tests = ['{[]}', '[(])','()[]{}', '{[](){}}', '']
for test in tests:
    print(test, validar(test))
```

produce:

```
{[]} True
[(]) False
()[]{} True
{[](){}} True
 True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Tio Moe!